# Import ESM without extension in Node/TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a sample typescript/node project, check it from my Github: https://github.com/hantsy/code-challenges/tree/master/transaction-analyzer/node-typescript

It used tsc to compile the whole project, run the project with `node` command, check [build scripts](https://github.com/hantsy/code-challenges/blob/master/transaction-analyzer/node-typescript/package.json#L9) defined in the *package.json* file.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "lint": "eslint --fix src/**/*.ts",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js"
  },
```

It is based on Microsoft node/typescript templates. Everything works well, but recently a dependency I used in this project is switched to ESM and it does not provides a CommonJS module.

I followed the [official Typescript Guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) to convert my project to use ESM import.

- add `type: module` to *package.json* file.
- change the tsconfig `module` option to *nodenext*.

But when I ran the project with `npm run start`. I will get the following errors.

```bash
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\hantsylabs\code-challenges\transaction-analyzer\node-typescript\dist\app' imported from D:\hantsylabs\code-challenges\transaction-analyzer\node-typescript\dist\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:231:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:850:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:654:28)
    at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:309:30)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:312:26)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:172:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I am using the latest **Node 19.8.x**.

```bash
> node -v
v19.8.1
```

I have tried the solutions in Stackoverflow or Google result, eg. add `experimental-specifier-resolution` parameter to node command, or install `extensionless` module, etc. None resolves my issues.

Comment: you should try to downgrade your dep that switched to ESM to a previous version that worked with CommonJS. Otherwise you need to switch all your deps to versions that support ESM. As far as I know there's no way to have both

Comment: Sadly to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That once happened to me too, chalk has switched to esm in v5, so I had to downgrade to v4. Most times you need to downgrade a package but in your case the issue is that **when switching to ESM you need to add a extension to every import in your files.**

Comment: I know this tip.  What I need is **do not change my current codes and import the js file without extensions** as it is.

Comment: OK, I will switch to use an old version.